# Way to detect if a polymer web animation is complete?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm struggling a bit with trying to find something to detect when the animation is complete. Any ideas? Maybe an event listener or something? I also don't know if this is the best way to actually play the animation..

```
    $(showMore).click(function () {
              var shrinky = new Animation(showMore, [{transform: 'scale(1)'}, {transform: 'scale(0)'}], {fill: 'forwards', duration: 500, easing: 'ease-out'});
              document.timeline.play(shrinky);
    });
```

Like can I detect when the scale is 0 somehow? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
- Shan

edit: it seems that my animation isn't firing a 'finish' event when it's over, and it should. maybe I just made the animation incorrectly..

**edit okay the solution is that i was trying to call the 'finish' event on the animation and not the animationPlayer. the proper code is this:**

```
var shrinky = new Animation(showMore, [{transform: 'scale(1)'}, {transform: 'scale(0)'}], {fill: 'forwards', duration: 500, easing: 'ease-out'});
    var playShrink = document.timeline.play(shrinky);
    playShrink.addEventListener('finish', function() {
    console.log('this is done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the animation fires an 'end' event (I haven't tried this myself yet).

```
shrinky.addEventListener('end', function() {
  doSomething
});
```

Comment: Hmm getting an undefined for that function -- Is this documented somewhere? I didn't see anything about an end event on the web-animations page, unless I'm missing a key resource somewhere.. hmm

Comment: I'm basically trying to get the element to be removed after the animation is done, like it shrinks done and then pops! and is gone. I tried detecting if scale = 0 but it detects it at the start of the animation for some reason and just removes the element immediately

Comment: Weird I haven't found it today but I found a testcase testing the 'finish' event https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/blob/master/test/testcases/test-player-finish-event.html

Comment: hmm tried it with finish also but no dice.. I noticed they used the done() method from jQuery in that code and tried that with my shrinky animation but it doesn't recognize shrinky as being something that has an end

Comment: This doc lists some changes http://w3c.github.io/web-animations/#changes-since-last-publication. I have no idea if they were implemented (removed onfinish, added ready, finished)

Comment: Here is the test using the 'end' event - just to show that I didn't make it up ;-) https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/blob/master/test/testcases/manual-test-add-player-onend.html

Comment: ooh maybe the issue is that i need to call the finish event on the animationPlayer and not the animation itself, one sec let me check

Comment: ok yes that was the issue. While the end event doesn't work (maybe not implemented yet?) the 'finish' event did work when calling it on the animationPlayer not the animation itself. thanks so much for the help! :-)